# Is there any difference between sync FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut() and async AuthUI.getInstance().signOut()

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

`FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut()` and `AuthUI.getInstance().signOut()` both sign out the user.

However, the first returns `void` while the other returns a `Task`.

Is there a difference when calling one instead of the other, for example can  `FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut()` fail? (whereas `OnComplete/OnSuccess` of `AuthUI.getInstance().signOut()` make us sure that it correctly signed out the user)

Or another difference perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference between the two. This `FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut()` will log out the user and `AuthUI` will do the same. But the class `AuthUI` is from the library firebaseui.

From the [docs](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/auth/README.md):

> FirebaseUI is an open-source library that offers simple, customizable UI bindings on top of the core Firebase SDKs. It aims to eliminate boilerplate code and promote best practices (both user experience and security) for authentication.

https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/auth/README.md#authui-sign-in

Comment: Why an async and a sync?

Comment: Are u using firebaseui?

Comment: If u check the code https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/auth/src/main/java/com/firebase/ui/auth/AuthUI.java#L389 you can see that they are calling signOut of type FirebaseAuth.

Comment: The method you linked shows that AuthUI also signs the user out from any identity providers (which prevents it from auto-signing in with those accounts later). That's also the reason it's an async method, as signing out from the providers is/may be an asynchronous operation.

Comment: Yes that's true